# Select child's child in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, children

I would like to select a child's child like this:

```
var button = childNode(withName: "button") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Inside the `SKSpriteNode` "alert" there is the `SKSpriteNode` "button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when selecting a child use `childNode(withName: "button")` which is shorthand for `self.childNode(withName: "button")` self being whatever class you are in (or the scene). To call a child of an object use...

```
let alert = self.childNode(withName: "alert") as! SKSpriteNode
var button = alert.childNode(withName: "button") as! SKSpriteNode
```